# Module Page not translated on changing language

Tags: php, controller, translation, prestashop

I have an issue with the front controller of my module in Prestashop v1.5

My module has a front controller that renders a separate tpl file. When I change language of my store from the front controller (i.e. my module page at front end), then page reloads but the module is not translated to the new language.

And when I do the same on home page or any other page and then move to my module page, the module is translated properly as expected.

This issue is coming on Prestashop v1.5 only, it is working fine on v1.6

Even if I print the context variable for language the language is updated there as well, but my module page is not translated.